# Rudin PMA Example 9.18 definition of the gradient vector

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I have a question regarding the definition of the gradient vector at a point given by Rudin. I am trying to derive why (33) in the passage is true which is given by:
$$g'(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n(D_if)(\gamma(t))\gamma'_i(t)$$

What I can see is that by the chain rule, we have that

$g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ in which both sides are linear transformations from $\mathbb{R^1}$ to $\mathbb{R^1}$ and the right side is a composition of linear transformations. However, how can I write this using theorem 9.17 such that it resembles the above sum but in terms of the basis vectors?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Indeed, your question is not really clear. The vector basis $e_j$ and $u_j$ appear in the formula of theorem 9.17 only because $f$ is now a vector valued function.